# Foundation 6 alert message with content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I'm working with Rail 4.2.5 and Foundation 6. I'm trying to close an alert message but seems not to be closing with that smooth effect; it's just a sharp close. The raw html, that works, is:

```
<div class="alert callout" data-closable>
  <h5>This is Important!</h5>
  <p>But when you're done reading it, click the close button in the corner to dismiss this alert.</p>
  <p>I'm using the default <code>data-closable</code> parameters, and simply fade out.</p>
  <button class="close-button" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

In my `application.html.erb`, I want to replicate with `content_tag`:

```
<% flash.each do | name, message | %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "#{name} callout", :"data-closable" => "data-closable"  do -%>
    <%= message %>
    <%= link_to('', html_options = {:"data-label" => "Dismiss alert" , :"data-close" => "data-close" }, class: "close-button") do-%>
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    <% end -%>
   <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "#{name} callout", :data => { :closable => '' }  do -%>
```

Comment: Thank you! All fades smooth.